# showing variable values with special characters

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I'm making a simple example for multilanguage website, where i'm saving all different text values in an array inside an unique php file.

```
<?php include_once 'common.php';?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php echo $lang['PAGE_TITLE']; ?></title>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1><?php echo $lang['HEADER_TITLE']; ?></h1>
    <h3><?php echo $lang['SLOGAN']; ?></h3>
</div>
<form name="lang" id="languages" method="post" action="">
    Language: 
    <select name="lang" onchange="document.lang.submit()">
        <option value="pt" <?php if($lng=="pt"){echo'selected';}?>>Português</option>
        <option value="en" <?php if($lng=="en"){echo'selected';}?>>English</option>
        <option value="es" <?php if($lng=="es"){echo'selected';}?>>Español</option>
    </select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the common.php

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

if(isSet($_POST['lang']))
{
$lng = $_POST['lang'];

// register the session and set the cookie
$_SESSION['lang'] = $lng;

setcookie("lang", $lng, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
}
else if(isset($_SESSION['lang']))
{
$lng = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
else if(isset($_COOKIE['lang']))
{
$lng = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}
else
{
$lng = 'pt';
}

switch ($lng) {
  case 'pt':
  $lang_file = 'lang.pt.php';
  break;

  case 'en':
  $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
  break;

  case 'es':
  $lang_file = 'lang.es.php';
  break;

  default:
  $lang_file = 'lang.pt.php';

}

include_once 'languages/'.$lang_file;
?>
```

and here is one of the laguage files (with special characters).

```
<?php
$lang = array();

$lang['PAGE_TITLE'] = 'Primeiro Website Multílingua';
$lang['HEADER_TITLE'] = 'Primeiro Website Multílingua';
$lang['SITE_NAME'] = 'Primeiro Website Multílingua';
$lang['SLOGAN'] = 'Escolhe a tua língua';
?>
```

Basically the character-set/encoding is not working as UTF-8
I've tried already with the http header() request, i thought it could be due to the fact the file is being called before the meta tag, changed, but still nothing.

Comment: check if PHP file itself is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Sorry, not getting it! How do i do that?

Comment: it depends on the editor you use to write PHP files. However the point is that if you server content to browser as UTF-8 (via meta tag and/or http headers), the input (PHP file) must be properly encoded also. And e.g. on windows most of the editors uses different encodings.

Comment: The editor is workig fine, cuase it only happens when i save somaething on one of thoose files language files, every single special chacracter saved in elsewhere works fine.

I've tried the php.ini, the .htaccess, the headers and the meta tag... nothing is changing

Comment: I'm so sorry, you were write... i don't know where this files came from but the php metadad declared on it probably was wrong, i'm created a new file, copy and pasted everything and now its fine!
Thanks for your help :D